# Is there any function which can transform string into expression?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(Math.sqrt(4));
let str = 'Math.sqrt(4)';
console.log(str);
```

Is there any way for the 2nd console.log to show 4?
Is there any function which can do this?

Comment: Last I checked the square root of 4 is 2. Also: [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is evil.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), like

```
let str = eval('Math.sqrt(4)');
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use the `eval()` function to evaluate the code in the string. Like this:

```js
let str = 'Math.sqrt(4)';
console.log(eval(str));
```